# Cocoa-Touch: use button or UIImage for clickable image?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uibutton

I'm building a iOS app which involves lots of photos displayed as rectangular areas on the screen. You can click on that area and see a bigger version of the photo. Kind of like those wallpaper apps, where you first see a grid layout of small wallpapers and then you can go in to see a bigger version.

So, I'm wonder what's the pros/cons in terms of memory usage and scalability between setting them up as UIButton (w/ background) and UIImageView?

Comment: I suggest `UIButton` for ease of use, but my guess is a `UIImageView` could be more efficient (if you implement everything well). At the end of the day it shouldn't make too much of a difference, so go with the `UIButton`'s ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an UIButton. It's easier to use as a user because it's made for touching them. Since UIImageView directly inherits from UIView it doesn't really know targets and selectors. So you'd have to implement this using touchesBegan:withEvent:. UIImageView is more efficient at drawing pictures though. UIButton already knows that so you'd only have to set the picture.